# Review the given batch commands to get the respective ChromeDriver to be downloaded based on Chrome browser version

Tags: selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I know the Selenium 4 version will take care of downloading the latest Chrome Driver. Also, Boni Garcia's web driver manager is also there for lower version. Though the given below batch commands can be used for Windows machines alone, I would like to get the feedback/inputs from all regarding the below. It may help someone who are not yet updated the Selenium version and facing version conflict issue between Chrome Driver and Chrome browser version.

```
SET workspace=<Path-where-chromedriver-to-be-downloaded...>
cd C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0
for /f %%R in ('powershell -command "&{[System.IO.File]::Exists('C:\\Program Files\\Google\\Chrome\\Application\\chrome.exe')}"') do (set CHROME64BIT=%%R)
if %CHROME64BIT%==True (for /f %%R in ('powershell -command "&{(Get-Item 'C:\\Program Files\\Google\\Chrome\\Application\\chrome.exe').VersionInfo.ProductVersion.Substring(0, 3)}"') do (set ChromeVersion=%%R))
if %CHROME64BIT%==False(for /f %%R in ('powershell -command "&{(Get-Item 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Google\\Chrome\\Application\\chrome.exe').VersionInfo.ProductVersion.Substring(0, 3)}"') do (set ChromeVersion=%%R))
set ChromeMajorVersion=https://googlechromelabs.github.io/chrome-for-testing/LATEST_RELEASE_%ChromeVersion:~0,3%
echo %ChromeMajorVersion%
cd C:\Program Files\Git\mingw64\bin
for /f %%R in ('curl.exe %ChromeMajorVersion%') do (set CompactDriverVersion=%%R)
if %CHROME64BIT%==True (curl.exe https://storage.googleapis.com/chrome-for-testing-public/%CompactDriverVersion%/win64/chromedriver-win64.zip --output %workspace%\ChromeDriver.zip)
if %CHROME64BIT%==False (curl.exe https://storage.googleapis.com/chrome-for-testing-public/%CompactDriverVersion%/win32/chromedriver-win32.zip --output %workspace%\ChromeDriver.zip)
cd C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0
powershell.exe Expand-Archive -Path %workspace%\chromedriver.zip -DestinationPath "%workspace%"
cd "%workspace%"
del ChromeDriver.zip
if %CHROME64BIT%==True (ECHO webdriver.chrome.driver= %workspace%\chromedriver-win64\chromedriver.exe >> ChomeDriverPath.properties)
if %CHROME64BIT%==False (ECHO webdriver.chrome.driver= %workspace%\chromedriver-win32\chromedriver.exe >> ChomeDriverPath.properties)
```